# Uploading .doc, .pdf or image file to Windows azure mobile services

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to upload or download .doc, .pdf or any image file to azure mobile services storage. If possible can anyone please provide me same samples.

Answer (score 0):

if by storage you meant, Azure Blob Storage, yes.

here's some links :

[Upload images to Windows Azure Storage by using Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-upload-data-blob-storage/)

[Upload File to Windows Azure Blob Storage using Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190)